# Heatbed module control with Raspberry Pi 3+

Tags: pwm, mosfet

I want to control a nichrome wire with the PWM signal from a Raspberry Pi. The MOSFET modules that can be found on the net for the combination with a Raspberry became much too hot. So I decided to try a [heatbed module](https://shop.lerdge.com/products/heated-bed-power-expansion-module) from Lerdge for 3D printers, which can handle much higher loads.

[image: Heatbed Module]

I connect the control input to the Raspberry Pi 3+ I'm using and the power input of the module to 24V DC. To the clamps marked with Heatbed I connected both ends of the nichrome wire. The power led lights up and when I send a PMW signal from the Raspberry the control led flickers in time with the signal but the nichrome wire stays cold. I also do not measure any voltage between the heatbed terminals. No matter whether with or without PWM signal.
I have three identical modules and they all behave identically. Therefore, I do not think that the MOSFET is broken.

Has anyone ever successfully controlled such a module with a Raspberry Pi (or similar) and can tell me where my error is?

Comment: 3D printer motherboards tend to work from 12 or 24 volts. As such motherboards would typically drive the heater I'd expect the PWM input needs to be more that 3V3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly I think such a module would be overkill just to heat a NiCr wire.

I use a suitable MOSFET with a heatsink to do similar, although I control with an Arduino (which has easier PWM and higher voltage).

Power MOSFET generally require a higher gate voltage than the Pi can provide.
If you want to use the Pi you will need an amplifier to boost the PWM voltage such as a small MOSFET or transistor. If you need help designing such a circuit you should ask on the E&E site.

Comment: It does work, when I use a logic level converter from 3V3 to 5V so you are absolutely right.